# React Native Picker Not Rendering Options

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, picker

I'm trying to implement a select dropdown menu in a React Native application using npm's `react-native-dropdown-picker` package.

I successful did it in one of the application's views/screens and tried to replicate by the same way but the dropdown menu is not rendering the options.

Checking the redux's store is possible to see the data that should be rendered, and in other view it does render. The data is the same for both screens such as the picker component.

```
return (
    <>
      <DefaultHeader navigation={navigation} />
      <Container>
        <ScrollView
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={refreshing}
              onRefresh={() => setRefreshing(true)}
            />
          }>
          <SalesAccountFilter /> // <-- Dropdown is rendered but dont render options
          {isLoading === true ? (
            <View style={{marginTop: '50%'}}>
              <Spinner color="#054785" />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <Content>
              ...some content
            </Content>
          )}
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
    </>
);
```

In the other screen that the dropdown is implemented in the exactly same way it is working fine. There is no error about it on the console. In the following snippet is the implementation of "SalesAccountFilter".

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  picker: {
    maxWidth: 320,
    minWidth: 320,
    color: 'black',
    zIndex: 1000,
  },
  pickerPlaceholder: {
    color: '#bfc6ea',
  },
});
...
  return (
    <DropDownPicker
      style={styles.picker}
      items={[...accounts]}
      defaultValue={null}
      placeholder="Select an account . . ."
      placeholderStyle={styles.pickerPlaceholder}
      containerStyle={{height: 40, width: 320}}
      labelStyle={{
        fontSize: 14,
        textAlign: 'left',
        color: '#000',
      }}
      itemStyle={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}
      dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
      onChangeItem={handleSelected}
      searchable={true}
      searchablePlaceholder="Search account"
      searchableError={() => <Text>Not found</Text>}
      activeLabelStyle={{color: 'blue'}}
    />
  );
```

```
**Versions:** 
Ubuntu 20.04lts;
Node v15.5.0;
React Native Picker 1.9.8;
React 17.0.1;
Nativebase 2.15.0;
React Native 0.63.4;
Emulator: Pixel 4 (latest build);
```

Comment: Can you add the output of`console.log(accounts)`

Comment: Look, I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the data. I'm using Reactotron and React Devtools to debug it and I can visualize the account's array and I am able to see the data on the Dropdown component. I guess it is a rendering issue related to the visual properties such as Zindex or native component's hierarchy.

Comment: did you tried by removing `defaultValue={null}` ?

Comment: What does the object `accounts` looks like ? Does it contain `value` and `label` keys?

Comment: @DipanshKhandelwal There are two screens using the same component, the accounts can't be a problem, otherwise none of the screens would render the view, but one of the two views does render and is able to select accounts as well.

Comment: @emkarachchi it is not the problem, otherwise the component would not work as it does in the other screen.

Comment: picker working for first component or 2nd second component? I think accounts is null before render the component.